# Relating inflation maps from spectral sequences in lower and higher dimensions

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, spectral-sequences

The spectral sequence has some nice property.
Consider $ N \to G  \overset{R}{\to} Q $ and  $G/N=Q$. There is a spectral sequence $\{E^{p,q}_n, d_n\}$ with: (i) The differential is defined as a map $d_n$: $E^{p,q}_n \to E^{p+n,q-n+1}_n$. Here $E^{p,q}_{n+1}={\text{Ker} (d_n)}/{\text{Im} (d_n)}$ on $E^{p,q}_{n}$. (ii) $E^{p,q}_2 = H^p(Q, H^q(N,M ))$.

Here let us take $M$ as a continuous Abelian Lie group $M=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}=S^1=U(1)$.

I know the fact that

$\bullet$ The image of the differential
$ d_2:  H^{D-2}(Q, H^{1}(N, M )) \to H^{D}(Q, M)$
provides elements of cocycles $\alpha_D^G \in H^{D}(Q, M)$, such that
all such elements in the image of the $d_2$ map are guaranteed to be within the kernel of the inflation map so as to be trivial as a coboundary in $H^{D}(G, M)$. Call this set-up as in the dimension $D$.

> $\bullet$ My question: Suppose given a fix dimension $D$, given a $Q$, we successfully find a particular $G$, such that $ N \to G  \overset{R}{\to} Q $ provides an inflation from $Q$ to $G$, so that a cocycle $\alpha_D \in H^{D}(Q, M)$ (that cocycle $\alpha_D$ is not a coboundary) becomes a coboundary in $H^{D}(G, M)$.
>
> How could we know that the related inflation map also works in a one higher dimension, changing from $D$ to $D+1$? In other words, given a fix dimension $D+1$, given a $Q$, can we successfully find another $G'$ (which $G'$ can be the same $G$ or a new $G'=G \times G_0$ related to $G$ by a group $G_0$), such that $ N' \to G'  \overset{R'}{\to} Q$ provides an inflation from $Q$ to $G'$, so that a cocycle $\alpha_{D+1} \in H^{D+1}(Q, M)$ (that cocycle $\alpha_{D+1}$ is not a coboundary) becomes a coboundary in $H^{D+1}(G', M)$? Or even more generic for a new $Q'$, via $ N' \to G'  \overset{R'}{\to} Q'$? (where $Q'$ can be a larger group than $Q$, related by a group $Q_0$, e.g. $Q'=Q \times Q_0$.)

--

p.s. Apology that my question is kind of general and less-constrained: In short, to search for such a new $G'$ in a one higher dimension from $D$ to $D+1$ based on a previous known successful inflation $G  \overset{R}{\to} Q$ in $D$-dimensions, how can we say something smart about the potential $G'  \overset{R'}{\to} Q$ in $D+1$-dimensions? Even so, for a new $Q'$ (that $Q'$ is related to $Q$ by a product to a group, etc), $G'  \overset{R'}{\to} Q'$  in $D+1$-dimensions? Any comments, criticisms and partial answers are highly encouraged and very welcome.

Comment: Please give some more background. It seems that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and because the tag is _group cohomology_, you are probably looking at group cohomology or cohomology of $BG$, $BQ$ rather than cohomology of $G$ and $Q$ themselves? And then the spectral sequence is a group cohomology version of the Leray-Serre spectral sequence? And is the inflation map then just the quotient map, or something else?

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. It is  group cohomology. (Or you can consider the cohomology of classifying space, too.) We concern the Lyndon–Hochschild–Serre spectral sequence. Yes there is a short exact sequence such that $G/N=Q$.

Comment: @Sebastian Goette, since the precise forms of $Q'$ and $G'$ are not given, I am probing the audience what we can say something intelligent -- it is kind of open to have more than one answer.